# how to hide/show action bar in fragment with scrollview

Tags: android, android-viewpager, material-design

Having problem for hide or show action bar in fragment with scrollview below is my code

```
scView=(ScrollView)view.findViewById(R.id.vertical_scrollview_id);
        scView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if(scView.getScrollY()>120){
                     if(action.isShowing()){
                         action.hide();
                     }
                 }else if(scView.getScrollY()<50){
                     if(!action.isShowing()){
                         action.show();                          
                     }
                 }
                   return;
            }
        });
```

i have used material design and view pager

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting crashes? Is is not working? Edit more code in where you initialize your action variable

Comment: it is working but i am not able to identify scroll is up or down

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom implementation of `ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener`

```
public abstract class ScrollViewScrollListener implements
                      ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener {

    private static final int SCROLL_THRESHOLD = 30;
    private ScrollView mScrollView;
    private int mScrollPosition;

    /**
     * Default constructor
     * @param scrollView to calculate the distance scrolled.
     */
    public ScrollViewScrollListener(ScrollView scrollView) {
        mScrollView = scrollView;
        mScrollPosition = scrollView.getScrollY();
    }

    @Override
    public final void onScrollChanged() {
        int scrollY = mScrollView.getScrollY();
        if (Math.abs(scrollY - mScrollPosition) > SCROLL_THRESHOLD) {
            onScrolled(scrollY - mScrollPosition < 0);
            mScrollPosition = scrollY;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the attached scrollview has been scrolled
     * @param scrolledUp true indicating the scroll view has scrolled in upward direction,
     *                   false indicating a downward scroll
     */
    public abstract void onScrolled(boolean scrolledUp);
}
```

Now attach this listener to your `ScrollView`

```
scView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ScrollViewScrollListener(scView) {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged(boolean scrolledUp) {
            if(scrolledUp) {
                //scrolled up show the actionbar
            } else {
                //scrolled down hide the actionbar
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: it is not working as i want it is flashing on some position

Comment: Elucidate your expected behavior

Comment: @blkerai edited code, this should work as expected. Tweak the `SCROLL_THRESHOLD` to get optimal results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CoordinatorLayout for that purpose?

Here you have a tutorial which explains it.

http://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling%28part1%29/